# Are these specks in my ceramic tile its design or stubborn dirt?

Tags: cleaning, ceramic-tile

I've recently moved into a rental property and the tile floor (ceramic I believe) in the corridor doesn't look very clean. I've tried mopping and scrubbing it with various combinations of vinegar,hot water, baking powder and dishwashing liquid but I don't seem to be making any sort of impact. My landlord reckons it's just how the tiles are meant to look but I'm not so convinced. Am I wrong? I'm thinking of purchasing a steam cleaner to see if that shifts it. Is there any other cleaning technique worth trying?
[image: closeup of dirty tiles]
[image: recently mopped tile]
Hopefully these pictures are clear enough!

Comment: I see nothing but speckled glazed tile there. If it doesn't come off with a scrub pad, it's tile. Put a strong light at a low angle and you'll see that the reflection is clean.

Comment: Heck, even the grout is still clean in those photos. Gray grout usually ends up black in such a situation before long.

Comment: That may well be the case, however the speckling seems quite inconsistent which is what makes me unsure. Perhaps I'll give it a steam clean and just leave it after that. If it really is some ingrained dirt that can survive steam cleaning then I'm sure it won't come off on my feet and spread around the rest of the house!

Comment: Dirt doesn't get ingrained in tile glaze. It's like glass. And the speckling is _supposed_ to be random. That's what gives it more of a hand-made quality. I think you need to quit obsessing. Even if you polish it to surgical table cleanliness, as soon as you walk on it that's out the door. All you'll serve to accomplish is to get the grout dirtier with all your scrubbing. :)

Comment: use a kitchen knife to scrape off one of the bits of "dirt" ... you will probably find that it is under the tile surface